# ArgumentException Cannot convert Int32 to Decimal in test parameter

Tags: c#, windows, unit-testing, nunit

I'm setting up a new integration server and I've been seeing tests fail with the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.Decimal'.
```

These tests run without issue in many other environments. A teammate suggested I look at Regional Settings on the new machine. The settings are identical with those of the other environments.

Here's a sample of what I'm seeing:

```
    [TestCase(1, TestName = "SampleTest_ArgumentIsInt")] // this test fails
    [TestCase(1.0, TestName = "SampleTest_ArgumentIsDouble")] // this test passes
    public void ShouldBeOkay(decimal arg)
    {
        ...test stuff...
    }
```

The failure is not related to an assert in the test. As indicated in the TestCase when the argument is unambiguously a decimal the ArgumentException does not occur.

The second TestCase implements the proximate fix. But I'd like to understand the root cause: why is the error occurring in one environment but in none of the others?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

---

Per commenters request here's the stack trace that Team City is reporting:

```
Test(s) failed. System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.Decimal'.
    at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
    at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
    at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
    at NUnit.Core.Reflect.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object fixture, Object[] args)
    at NUnit.Core.TestMethod.RunTestMethod(TestResult testResult)
    at NUnit.Core.TestMethod.doTestCase(TestResult testResult)
```

Comment: Show the full exception stack trace.

Comment: Is there a value in InnerException? nUnit uses Convert.ChangeType() http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5 which does not throw ArgumentException.

Comment: I've posted the stack trace Team City is reporting in the original post. I am not seeing an inner exception.

Comment: Maybe it is related to which .NET Framework version you are running on the new integration server? BTW, I would actually argue that `1.0` is NOT a `decimal` type; to ensure that your number is interpreted as *type* `decimal` you should use post-fix `m`, i.e. `1.0m` or `1m`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Anders. I'll check the .NET versions and post my findings. Regarding the post-fix: NUnit does not allow it -- throws an error complaining that an attribute argument must be a constant expression. So, yes the argument is a double in this case but that seems to satisfy the NUnit converter. [I've updated the sample code to reflect the correct datatypes.]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by updating NUnit to the latest version. I chased my tail for awhile until a colleague noted that the NUnit version on the *new* server was several versions older than the latest which we're using on all of our other CI machines.

The failing tests all used NUnit parameterized test case attributes [TestCase...] where NUnit is passing the arguments into the test methods and does a conversion as needed.

Thanks to commenters for taking time to help.

I hope this answer helps others running across the same issue.